# Can android developers access the system clock/alarm application?

Tags: android, clock, alarm

My Nexus S comes with a default clock application where I can set an alarm. When I set an alarm then I see a little clock in my status bar.

If I go to 'Manage Applications' or 'Running Services', I would expect to see Clock there, but I don't?

If I go to 'All' from 'Manage Applications', then I do see the Clock app, and I can Force Quit it, however the clock in the status bar still appears.

If the default Clock application never appears in Running Applications or Services because it is part of the system, then can developers access this Clock app? For instance I am creating an alarm application, should it be possible to hookup the alarms from my application to the system Clock app?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the alarm clock is a system service, which may be why it is not visible to you. There is only one clock on each device, so any alarm you make will utilize the system clock in some form or another. [Here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/02/android-basics-alarm-service/) is an old tutorial for making an alarm using AlarmManager. And [here is a link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm) to an API demo on the dev pages for making an alarm.

Comment: Thanks - I am successfully able to create an alarm using AlarmManager and the ALARM_SERVICE in my app and the alarm goes off when expected. However, these alarms do not show up in the default system Clock app, only in my app. Should it be possible to show alarms that are using the system ALARM_SERVICE in the default system Clock application, or will the Clock application only show alarms that were set within it (and not from other apps)?

Comment: I think the only way to have them show up in the default app is to set the alarm in that app. You can start an activity using [AlarmClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) to have the default app handle the alarm. You could also attempt to have your app handle all alarms. I'd have to research how to do it, but it would deal with setting things up properly in the manifest.

Comment: There's a SET_ALARM intent that almost all stock and most play store alarm clock apps support.