# Is it possible to access programmatically a default application from my own application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android development (using **Android Studio**) and I decided to create my own application that would access programmatically the default clock application from an android phone (*Galaxy s7*) in order to set, update or delete alarms from that default clock app.

Is this possible to do or is it better to create an alarm component within my own application?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8493917/9274948

Comment: yes, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

There's specific techniques that you can use to talk to another application on Android. [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) are two examples.

The thing is, for that to work the app that you want to talk to must expose a public interface that you can call either by sending intents, starting activities or binding to services.

For the particular case of clock app i don't think that such public interface exists. You will need to implement your own alarm component.